# Glassfish ClassCastException WebBundleContext and EjbContext

Tags: web-services, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have been having a hard time getting a simple web service deployed to GlassFish 3.1.1 I keep getting the following exception on deploy:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.context.WebBundleContext cannot be cast to com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.context.EjbContext
    at org.glassfish.webservices.annotation.handlers.WebServiceProviderHandler.processAnnotation(WebServiceProviderHandler.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344)
    ... 42 more

Here is my WebService Class:

```
@Stateless
@WebServiceProvider(
    serviceName = "HelloWorldProviderService",
    portName = "HelloWorldProviderPort",
    targetNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/wsdl"
)
@ServiceMode(value= Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
public class HelloWorldProvider implements Provider<Source>
{
    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source request)
    {
        StringWriter requestXmlWriter = new StringWriter();

        try
        {
            Transformer copier = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            copier.transform(request, new StreamResult(requestXmlWriter));
            System.out.println(requestXmlWriter.toString());

            return new StreamSource(new StringReader("<HelloBack/>"));
        }
        catch (TransformerException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert");
        }
    }
}
```

The war layout is

```
|__ WEB-INF
|          |__ web.xml
|
|__ classes
|       |__ META-INF
|       |      |__ ejb-jar.xml
|       |
|       |__ <classfile>
|
|__ lib
|    |__ <empty>
```

This works in my test environment using OpenEjb but I need it to work against GlassFish and suggestions would be great.

Thank You
   -kurt

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NetBeans? I ask because this is a known [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=178323) and was fixed in NetBeans version 6.9. Try upgrading NetBeans and see if that works for you.

Comment: Preston thank you for the response, I read that same post but I'm using Intellij, what I did was remove the Stateless from the WebServiceProvider class and since it is within the container I have references to the resources so I was able to get it working.  I was mainly frustrated that in my test environment (OpenEJB) that the Stateless worked in conjunction with the WebServiceProvider annotation but not in GlassFish that is in production.  I had to modify the ejb-jar.xml in the test branch and declare it as a stateless bean to have access to the resources in the OpenEJB container.